# Python BeautifulSoup: Iterating over a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

I want to iterate over every TD of each TR tag. So, for example, if I get all tables:

`trList = tbody.findAll('tr')`

Later I want to get all the TD tags of each TR element separately.

Something like:

```
trList[0]:
  td[0]
  td[1] # I wanted to get this TD of every TR
  td[2]

trList[1]:
  td[0]
  td[1] # this one as well
  td[2]
```

In a normal situation, I'd get it with a nested loop.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, use the same function `findAll`

```
trList = tbody.findAll('tr')
for tr in trList:
    tdList = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in tdList:
        // here you got each td
```

Answer (score 4):

`nth-of-type` [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) would help here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for td in soup.select('table > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)'):
    print td.text
```

Prints:

```
2
5
8
```